# How to prevent an imported module from 'importing' sys.argv[1:]

Tags: python-2.7, command-line-arguments, python-module

I am a python newbie.  To pose my question in a comprehensible manner, I created two scripts.  One script is named: called_script.py   The other script is named: calling_script.py

The following two lines are the code in called_script.py

```
 import sys
 print str(sys.argv[1]) + '\n\n' + str(dir(sys.argv[1]))
```

The following two lines are the code in calling_script.py

```
 import sys
 import called_script
```

If I feed 'foo' as a command line argument to 'calling_script.py', foo will appear as sys.argv[1] in 'called_script.py'

Is there any code that I could add to 'called_script.py' so that 'called_script.py' could ascertain 
whether sys.argv[1] was passed to it from the command line, or whether sys.argv[1] was passed to it from '**main**'?

Also, I am curious to know whether it is possible to prevent e.g., sys.argv[1] from being passed from **main** to an imported module, and where I could find some reading on this topic.

Thank you for any help.  It is much appreciated.

```
                      Marc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any code that I could add to 'called_script.py' so that
>   'called_script.py' could ascertain whether sys.argv[1] was passed to
>   it from the command line, or whether sys.argv[1] was passed to it from
>   'main'?

Fundamentally, no, because command line arguments aren't passed to *modules*, they're passed to Python, which puts them in `sys.argv`.  Since all the modules are sharing the same `sys`, they'll all see the same `sys.argv`, and that's that.

That said, you can take advantage of `__name__`, which is set to `__main__` only for the main script:

```
~/coding$ python calling_script.py fred
called_script says __name__ is: called_script
calling_script says __name__ is: __main__
```

So you could use something like

```
args = sys.argv if __name__ == '__main__' else [whatever_you_want]
```

and then use `args` to get the equivalent of a module-specific `sys.argv`.  Similarly, you could branch on `__name__` at the very start of `calling_script.py`, stash `sys.argv`, and then modify the one in `sys` (ick).

But generally speaking, you shouldn't need to use `sys.argv` anywhere outside your main program anyway.  If you need access to `sys.argv` in multiple places your interface probably isn't separated enough from your routines.